# Django : No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts

Tags: python, django

I'm having a trouble on getting this error when filtering data on my postgresql, it says that the error comes from this line `.filter(bene_id='31452')`. I've been using two tables in Django. I think the problem is on my operator `=` since the id is integer but the problem is how and what should I replace in that operator ?

I tried putting double qoute, single qoute and even without elements like this `.filter(bene_id="31452")` ,`.filter(bene_id=31452)` ,`.filter(bene_id='31452')` . But it seems the error has not been solve.it would be great if anybody could figure out where I am doing something wrong. thank you so much in advance

*Error*

```
LINE 1: ...2_benes_status" WHERE "b2_benes_status"."bene_id" = 31452  L...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need 
to add explicit type casts.
```

*views.py*

```
Testing = B2BenesStatus.objects.using('matchy_data').filter(bene_id='31452')
```

*Models.py*

```
class B2BenesStatus(models.Model):
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    value = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    remarks = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    bene_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    stat_cat_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    updated_by_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'b2_benes_status'
```

*Settings.py*

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'payroll',
    'USER':'root',
    'PASSWORD':'',
    'HOST':'localhost',
    'PORT':'3306',

},
    'matchy_data': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'matchy_data',
    'USER':'postgres',
    'PASSWORD':'samplee',
    'HOST':'localhost',
    'PORT':'5432',
},}
```

Comment: Change your `id` in your lookup to an integer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3739808/no-operator-matches-the-given-name-and-argument-types-you-might-need-to-add-e

Comment: @PacketLoss but in my models it's already set as integerFiled `bene_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)`  , Did you mean It should be change this into TextField?

Comment: I think the problem is on my operator  `=` since the id is integer but the problem is how and what should I replace in that operator ?

Comment: ORM query is correct. Don't use qoutes because it's integer field. I suggest try again code without qoutes. I have not used second second database and postgresql, so if nothing work (and you have time), you can try a test model in default database with same fields and try this Testing = B2BenesStatus.objects.filter(bene_id=31452)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `bene_id` is really stored as an integer in your existing SQL database (please, double check that):

As `bene_id` is an `IntegerField`, `.filter(bene_id='31452')` will fail, because `'31452'` is a string type. Also, note there is no fundamental difference between `"` and `'` in Python.

You need pass an `int` type to the `bene_id` argument, something like `.filter(bene_id=31452)`.

You said you tried without string delimiters without success, but I suspect there is another problem behind then.

Comment: I just found out that the error is when I want to print that query  `Testing `. But it should suppose to be print? how should I display `Testing` value ?

Comment: As QuerySets are lazy, they are not evaluated instantly but when some following code actually uses them. `print(Testing)` should return the `__str__` representation of a `B2BenesStatus` object.

Answer (score 0):

`Testing = B2BenesStatus.objects.using('matchy_data').filter(bene_id__in=['31452'])`

-Now you will not get Error

> 100 % error free code
> if you have any doubts please ask here I'm ready to help you..
> [image]