# How to debug JPA CriteriaBuilder queries

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, eclipselink, criteria-api

How can I debug a query built with `JPA 2.0` `CriteriaBuilder`? Is there a way to print out the query that is being executed?

I am developing a web application using `NetBeans`, `MySql`, `GlassFish`. I would avoid starting MySql in debug mode, because it is used also for other applications. JPA provider is `EclipseLink`.

Comment: Which JPA provider do you use (e.g. OpenJPA, Hibernate)?

Comment: @home, I have added the info you have requested

Comment: No prob; check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374395/is-it-possible-to-output-generated-sql-using-eclipselink-without-having-to-incre

Comment: @home, since OP indicated GlassFish is being used, I guess EclipseLink would be a safe guess ;)

Comment: @Arjan: ... but still a guess :-)

Comment: Similar question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362876/how-to-view-the-sql-queries-issued-by-jpa][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362876/how-to-view-the-sql-queries-issued-by-jpa

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The same attributes in persistence.xml that also print the SQL that is generated from regular JPQL queries, should also print the SQL that is generated from Criteria queries.

E.g.

For Hibernate (used by e.g. JBoss AS) it's:

```
<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
```

For EclipseLink (used by e.g. GlassFish) it's:

```
<property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/>
<property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>
```

Also see: [How to view the SQL queries issued by JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362876/how-to-view-the-sql-queries-issued-by-jpa)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Java and Spring, under resources, you can adjust your `application.properties` file and add the line below:

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```