# Test jpql query before execution in jpa

Tags: jpa, orm, jpql

I want to know if JPA provides a way to test the parsing of a JPQL query just before the query gets executed.

Best regards,

Comment: you can use HSQLDB to test it, before your run your project (TDD)

Comment: thanks @LowLevel for your answer but I want to test the queries not only before running the project because in my application I add queries from external sources at runtime.

Comment: and if you catch an SQLException ?

Comment: Yes, this could be a solution to this problem. But this is the last option that I want to use.

Comment: why? what do you want to know with the test?

Comment: in the worst case, if you want to know what a jpql query tries to do, to prevent damage to your database, you can make your own parser. Kind of `QueryParser` > `QueryParser.isQueryValidated(String query)`

Comment: I might consider your solution.  I was just wondering why they do not provide testing options before going to SQLException.

Comment: I just mean it's great we have lots of useful frameworks, APIs, libraries, but it's not the goal to become a "victim of scopes" at all. If you don't find something, make it yourself. We always need something specific or something very specific, and the key objective is to get what you want to get.

Comment: JPA doesn't have it, but your JPA provider likely has native methods you can call directly.  Eclipse's Dali also has JPQL validation, and other IDEs might as well.

Comment: @Chris could you please give more details?

Comment: To which part?  Eclipse's Dali project or using your ORM's native methods to parse the query without executing it?   You are better off searching for info on Dali or your IDE yourself, and you haven't mentioned your JPA provider.  If you are using EcllipseLink, see the code example in the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/12104085/496099

Comment: Thanks @Chris for your answer. I use EcllipseLink. From the link you provided, I do not know how to test if a JPQL query is correct without executing it.

Comment: correct - do you mean it doesn't give you a validation exception when it gets processed into SQL, or that the SQL created is valid and returns you the expected results.  The code example does the first, only execution will ensure the second.

Answer (score 0):

No. The `JPA` spec doesn't provide an option to "compile" the query (unlike what the `JDO` persistence spec provides), so there is no **reliable** way of doing that. Some implementations compile at creation of the Query, and others just before execute.