# Show logging parameter for (INSERT,UPDATE,SELECT) in EclipseLink JPA

Tags: jpa, glassfish, eclipselink

I used logging in **persistence.xml** for EclipseLink JPA implementation, from 
[stackoverflow reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374395/is-it-possible-to-output-generated-sql-using-eclipselink-without-having-to-incre/2374467#2374467)
but the parameters appears as **`?`** how can i show them properly in my glassfish log output window.

Comment: so the accepted answer on that post does what you need ...

Comment: yes but its not accepted till two days to be viable for self acceptance ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The log level configuration is included in the definition of the persistence unit in the **persistence.xml** file, as follows:

The logging of SQL parameters can be enabled, or disabled through the following properties:

Disable:

Enable:

```
<property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINE"/>
<property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>
```

**full persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="ProjPU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/POS</jta-data-source>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="static" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINEST" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.cache" value="FINEST" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Note: Setting eclipselink.logging.level to **FINE** is not sufficient (as of **EclipseLink** 2.4.0 - Juno), you have to set **eclipselink.logging.level.sql** to **FINE**.

This property will also control how parameters are logged in exceptions. By default parameters are only logged for log level < **CONFIG**.

Refernce:[Documentation](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging),[Wiki Ecipse link](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging)