# How to store a BigDecimal correctly in a DB using JPA?

Tags: jpa, bigdecimal

I want to save an amount in the database using JPA.

```
@Column(precision=8, scale=2)  
private BigDecimal amount;
```

But after persisting, the decimal values are always 0.
E.g., when I create the amount with

```
amount = BigDecimal.valueOf(30.20D);
```

and store it to the database with em.persist(..), the value in the database is 30,00.
When I use a sql update command, I can set it to any value, no problem.

This seems very strange. 
I use EclipseLink and Sybase DB.

Comment: How is the column defined?

Comment: It's defined using  <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-or-extend-tables"/>

Comment: It's hard to guess what the problem is without debugging. I would recommend enabling the debug logs for the EclipseLink and investigate what parameters exactly it passes to DB.  [How to enable logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374395/is-it-possible-to-output-generated-sql-using-eclipselink-without-having-to-incre)