# Passing EclipseLink properties through Spring's application.properties?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, eclipselink

We use EclipseLink as our JPA provider.

I find a lot of answers online that talk about the `persistence.xml` solutions, but I'm actually trying to avoid using XML configuration. I even read that SpringBoot now doesn't even look for that file anymore unless told to. For this reason, I want to try to stick to `application.properties`.

It seems like Hibernate has decent support through passing `spring.jpa.hibernate` properties. However, I'm left hanging when it comes to EclipseLink.

I'm trying to:

1. Set the EclipseLink logging to `ALL` to help me debug.
2. Activate the EclipseLink Batch-Writing to see if I can improve the performance of my application.

This is my current `application.properties`:

```
logging.level.root=info
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing=JDBC
eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing.size=500
```

I tried plugging the values of [some of these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2374395/9768291) into the `application.properties` but it didn't really help me see SQL commands. The only way I could get to see some SQLs was with `spring.jpa.show-sql=true` which lead me to believe that it's not as trivial as I'd expect to avoid using `persistence.xml`. This also makes me suspect that the `eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing` properties are also not actually being recognized by EclipseLink.

---

We do log through `logback`. Maybe this `logback.xml` file content could be helpful:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="2 seconds" debug="false">

    <appender name="log.console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="com.foo.bar.app.LoggerLayoutEncoder">
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSSS} -\t%highlight(%-5level)\t%17.-17tenantContext\t%15.-15userContext\t%50.-50requestContext\tThread[%26.-26thread]%n\t\t\t\tLogger[%green(%36.36(%logger{36}))]\tMsg[%highlight(%msg)]%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="Sentry" class="io.sentry.logback.SentryAppender">
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>ERROR</level>
        </filter>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="log.console" />
        <appender-ref ref="Sentry" />     
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a bug in my company's internal framework which prevented the `eclipselink` properties from being inherited by the `EntityManager`.

Please disregard.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-
#spring.jpa.properties.eclipselink.logging.level.sql: ALL

[This](https://docs.actian.com/integrationmanager/2.1/index.html#page/User/ApplicationProperties.htm) can also help you, a few more properties of EclipseLink are defined here.

Comment: Interesting that only those `eclipselink` properties have the `#` comment character in front of them. Moreover, the default value would apparently already be `ALL` for the log level, and `true` for logging parameters. So in fact I shouldn't even have to specify those to see the logs. What is going on here? I tried setting them up anyways, and did not see a difference in the logging, unfortunately. :(